# Resize PDF pages and expand white background

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ghostscript, pdftk

**What I Have**

I have a PDF containing a series of photos.  Each photo occupies an entire A4-sized page.  That is, each page of the PDF contains 1 photo, and there is no border/background/canvas showing around the photo.

**What I Want**

I want to rescale the photos so that there is a page background showing around the photos.  In other words, I want each page to look like a blank white page with a photo at the center,  not occupying the whole page.

---

Idea: resize all the pages of the PDF, then create an empty white-background document with the same number of pages, and then put the resized-photos PDF on top of the empty-document PDF.  But... I don't know how to do this.

I do have Adobe Acrobat Pro, but I would prefer a `gs` or `pdftk` solution so I don't have to mess with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print the photo to PDF then go to "Page setup" and set custom dimensions for the paper size. Alternatively, you could select a preset paper size that is larger than you are looking for and simply crop after it has printed to the new file.

[image]

[image]